# Global section of a locally constant sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

Assume that $k$ is a field , $X$ a connected topological space, $L$ locally isomorphic to the constant sheaf $k_X$ and $\Gamma(X;L)\neq 0$.
I want to show that $L$ is actually isomorphic to the constant sheaf $k_X$.

Morally I understand that if we have a non zero global section of a locally constant sheaf on a connected space, then this section should be a constant function on the space $X$ and $L$ behaves as a constant sheaf. It resembles to me the fact that for projective varieties we don't have non constant global sections of the structure sheaf.

If $\Gamma(X;L)\neq 0$ then it must exist a nonzero morphism inside $Hom_{k_X}(k_X,L)$ but then I'm stuck here, I'd appreciate if anybody could give me an hint.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You are right that the assumption implies that there is a nonzero morphism $k_X\to L$, so pick one. Then consider the subset $Z\subseteq X$ consisting of points $x$ at which the induced map of stalks $k_{X,x}\to L_x$ is an isomorphism. As $k_X\to L$ is nonzero, this set is nonempty. It is not too hard to show that it is also both open and closed. By connectedness of $X$, we must then have $Z = X$, proving your claim.

PS. You may want to assume that your space is not just connected, but also locally connected or, to make things even easier, locally path-connected. If $X$ is locally path connected, then each $x\in X$ admits a nbhd $U\ni x$ so that for each $y\in U$, there is a commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
k_{X,x} @>{\sigma_x}>> L_x \\
@V{\cong}VV @V{\cong}VV \\
k_{X,y} @>{\sigma_y}>> L_y
\end{CD}
$$
so the bottom map is an iso iff the top map is an iso.